# Массив в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сделать, чтобы помимо основной функции, которая сейчас работает, в каждой строке массива количество его элементов увеличивалось на 1, т.е. в первой строке 1, во второй - 2, 4, в третьей - 3,6,9, в четвертой - 4, 8, 12, 16 и т.д. У меня так не получается.

```js
var n = 5;
var m = 1;
var s = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var arr = new Array();

  arr.push(m);
  m++;
  if (arr > 1) {
    var p = 2;

    for (var w = 1; w <= s; w++) {
      var z = arr[0] * p;
      arr.push(z);
      p++;
      while (s <= 5) {
        s++;
      }


    }
  }


  document.write(arr, "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

второй цикл немного намудрили. У вас итерируется переменная m в верхнем уровне, вот ее и используйте. Следовательно переменная s уже не будет нужна.

```js
var n = 5;
var m = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var arr = new Array();
  arr.push(m);
  m++;
  
  if (arr > 1) {
    var p = 2;

    for (var w = 1; w < m - 1; w++) {
      var z = arr[0] * p;
      arr.push(z);
      p++;
    }
  }

  document.write(arr, "<br>");
}
```

Comment: чем данный код отличается от того, что в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy тем что он работает

Comment: а почему ты думаешь что он работает?

Comment: Меня озадачивает такой допрос. А почему ВЫ думаете что он не работает?

Comment: Например, потому что не заметно отличие от кода в вопросе. Может быть код в вопросе так же работает?

Comment: jsFiddle на что? Я не вижу смысла с вами продолжать беседу, если вы не видите такие простые вещи в моем ответе (и ответе остальных). Извиниите я больше не буду отвечать на такие прозрачные и далекие коммантарии.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите конструкцию while и оставьте s++, пусть индекс поднимается после перехода на новую строку, а то Вы его изначально ставите максимальным, и по итогу в строке вместо нужного кол-ва символов всегда 1 + 6.

```js
var n = 5;
var m = 1;
var s = 1;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  var arr = new Array();

  arr.push(m);
  m++;
  if (arr > 1) {
    var p = 2;

    for (var w = 1; w <= s; w++) {
      var z = arr[0] * p;
      arr.push(z);
      p++;
     }
     s++;
  }


  document.write(arr, "<br>");
}
```

Comment: чем данный код отличается от того, что в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy запустите его, а потом оригинал, и посмотрите результат. Что за странные вопросы? Хоть прочитайте условие сперва

Comment: Так а отличается то чем? Почему ты думаешь, что тут результат правильный?

Comment: @Grundy наверное потому что прежде чем его постить я запустил его в отладчике? Конкретно ответ от заданного кода? Отсутствует конструкция While которая условно не нужна в таком коде

Comment: Пояснение должно быть непосредственно в ответе, а не просто непонятный кусок кода, который неизвестно что делает

Comment: @Grundy стоп, я исправил кусок который работал не так, как хотел пользователь, предложил ответ. Хотите пояснений? Я написал комментарий сразу под вопросом, что не так работает.